# Unable to run pex file as win32-cp-37-cp37m is missing

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to run a pex file provided by Adobe to sync users between our AD and their admin portal.

The command to test is

```
python user-sync.pex
```

I expect to get a list of command parameters

I get the following error:

```
Failed to execute PEX file, missing win32-cp-37-cp37m compatible
dependencies for:
user-sync
umapi-client
cffi
psutil
cryptography
pyyaml
pycryptodome
```

I have installed `pywin32` package but this has made no difference.

Comment: Have you come up with a solution for this yet? I'm currently facing the same thing with the Adobe user-sync.pex. Unfortunately, I haven't had much experience with Python, so far.

Comment: You have to use the version of Python to match the user sync tool. I had to download Python 3.6.8 to match the version of the user sync tool. https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.8/python-3.6.8-amd64.exe